# Reading about the null set and Lebesgue measure - asking for reading recommendation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I hope its allowed to ask a more "general" question here
I just started learning multivariable integral, and we just learned about the null set and Lebesgue measure ( in our defention we use cubes to define the lebesgue and null set)
and to be honest I feel a bit lost and that I dont really understand the subject.

I was hoping to get some reccomendation about books I could read on the subject, if it has some examples and solved exercises it will be wonderfull.

thanks to everyone

Comment: Older posts for measure theory reference requests: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46213/43949), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2400011/43949), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1134955/43949)

Comment: This is good: https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf